# angularfire2 array manipulation

Tags: angular, firebase

Whats the correct way to deal with arrays in firebase? I'm trying to toggle a value within an array or numbers when clicking a button. so each number exist only once, say button 12, is clicked, then 12 is added to the array in firebase, if clicked again then it's removed.

this is my code, however, it does not splice, the number is added again every time.

```
blockTime(time: number) {
const idx = _.indexOf(this.times, time);
if (idx >= 0) {
     this.times.splice(idx, 1);
   } else {

  this.times.push(time);
   }
}
```

Comment: `times ` is  firebase array?

Comment: yea, I get it like this 

   getDayTimes(day: string): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
   const dayPath =  `${this.basePath}/${day}`;
  this.times = this.db.list(dayPath);
   return this.times;
 }

Comment: splice will remove item from array but not from firebase

Comment: How would you go about it, if you wanted it removed from firebase?

Comment: remove the item and then push the new item

Comment: this [link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) will help you

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to toggle a value in an array, reconsider your data structure. Whenever you do `array.contains(...)` or `array.indexOf(...)` you probably should be using a set-like data structure.

Since JavaScript/JSON doesn't have real sets, you typically emulate them (on Firebase at least) by using an object with `true` values and your set-items as keys. Then suddenly you operation becomes a lot cleaner:

```
blockTime(time: number) {
  if (!this.times[time]) {
    this.times[time] = true;
  }
  else {
    delete this.times[time];
  }
}
```

Or if you're fine with keeping non-blocked time slots with a `false` value:

```
blockTime(time: number) {
  this.times[time] = !(this.times[time] || false);
}
```

Note that when storing this type of data in Firebase, it is best to make sure your keys are strings to avoid the array coercion of the Firebase SDKs. You can simply do this by prefixing the keys with a string, e.g.

```
blockTime(time: number) {
  var key = "time"+number;
  if (!this.times[key]) {
    this.times[key] = true;
  }
  else {
    delete this.times[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, this method feels right to me, maybe I'm not storing the data in the right way. do you have an example fo what the data structure would look like in firebase? I basically have a node called schedule, with a sub-node for each day of the week, the times is what I'm struggling with. thanks in advance

Comment: The data would look like the `groups` node here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout