# toggle boolean in firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using angular 4 and firebase with angularFire2,
I have a tree in firebase that looks like this

```
{
"monday": {
    "9": true,
    "10": true,
    "11": true,
    "12": true,
    "13": true,
    "14": true,
    "15": true,
    "16": true,
    "17": true,
    "18": true,
    "19": true
},
"tuesday": {
    "9": true,
    "10": true,
    "11": true,
    "12": true,
    "13": true,
    "14": true,
    "15": true,
    "16": true,
    "17": true,
    "18": true,
    "19": true
   },
}...
```

for each 'time' slot I'm rendering a button, what i want to accomplish in angularFire is toggle the boolean on click.

code i've tried

```
blockTime(time: number): void {
        const idx = _.indexOf(this.times, time);
        if (idx !== -1) {
                this.times.splice(idx, 1);
        } else {
                this.times.push(time);
        }
    }

///
this also
blockTime(time: number) {
  this.times[time] = !(this.times[time] || false);
}
```

I know I'm way off!

Comment: show the code you tried.

Comment: how you rendering the button

Comment: This seems closely related to my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079993/angularfire2-array-manipulation), so linking that for context.

Comment: The JSON you now have is **not** an array, so you shouldn't be using `splice()` and `push()` on it.

Comment: What is your problem with the current code? Doesn't it work? Are there errors? How do you invoke `blockTime()`?

Comment: Yea, I figured I was just showing the stuff I tried in the past, for context

Comment: <hours
    [times]='times | async'
    [availableTimes]='blockedTimes'
    (block)="scheduleService.blockTime($event)">
  </hours>

Comment: when I click each button, I don't get any errors, just nothing happens

Comment: you are not performing any firebase operations to update.

Comment: i think i need something like 
updateItem(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.times.update(key, value)
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
  }

but im having trouble getting the key

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure what the problem is, but the minimal function itself seems to work fine.

```js
var json = {
  "monday": {
    "9": true,
    "10": true,
    "11": true,
    "12": true,
    "13": true,
    "14": true,
    "15": true,
    "16": true,
    "17": true,
    "18": true,
    "19": true
  },
  "tuesday": {
    "10": false,
    "11": true,
    "12": true,
    "13": true,
    "14": true,
    "15": true,
    "16": true,
    "17": true,
    "18": true,
    "19": true
   }
};

function toggleTime(day, time) {
  json[day][time] = !(json[day][time] || false);
}
console.log(json);
toggleTime("monday", 9);
toggleTime("tuesday", 9);
toggleTime("tuesday", 10);
console.log(json);
```

The problem is more likely in how you invoke the function or how you bind to Angular. Please make sure that your question contains all code necessary to reproduce the problem. A good way to do this is to reproduce the problem in a tool like jsbin (since coding using Firebase Database can't run in a Stack Overflow snippet).

Comment: thank you very much for the help I'm gonna try this now

Comment: my issue i think is connecting it to firebase

Comment: That could indeed be. Please make sure your question includes that information as I describe at the bottom of my answer. I recommend reading on [how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which explains the rationale behind (and the way to) create such a repro.

Comment: Hey Frank, I'm really close to doing it!!
this is my function
 block(event: any, day): void {

  const dayPath =  `${this.basePath}/${day}`;
   this.db.object(dayPath)
    .update({  '9' : true });
}

however, I'm struggling with the  "{ '9': true} " part. not sure how to grab the correct time, $key doesn't work, or how to toggle the boolean.

Comment: I have no idea from that description what is going wrong. It's really hard to reproduce the full picture of the problem from snippets. Please take the time[create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question with that, as honestly: it's the best way to request help in a coding problem such as this.

Comment: Sorry about that, ended up doing this { [key]: true }